# Vertical Align Text in DIV

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I know this has been answered many time before, but I have tried soooo many times and now my code is all frankensteined together. I understand that using float tags can make the vertical-align not work properly but even when I took that out the text/link STILL didn't vertically align... I'm at a loss, my code is looking crappy and getting out of control. I tried just putting the style in the link tag itself instead of referencing a style sheet... Ug I need help. I'm not sure if you need all of the code, it's for an author box at the bottom of posts, and this is a little box that links to previous post by the same author.

HTML

```
<div class="home_icon">
<a href="%author_link% " style="display: block; font: bold 13px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma'; color: #fff; vertical-align: middle; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
 text-decoration: none;">
View all %post_count% posts by %name%  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .home_icon {
      width: 425px;
      height: 30px;
      float:right;
      font: bold 11px 'lucida sans', 'trebuchet MS', 'Tahoma';
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      background: #d83c3c;
      position: relative;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 0px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ;
}
.home_icon:before { 
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    right: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid #d83c3c;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have:

```
    vertical-align: middle;
```

Just add the following to the div.home_icon rule to get started:

```
    display: table-cell;
```

For all adjustments, [see this corresponding jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uehfR/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try: `margin-top: 6px;` for your a tag, in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution to your specific issue: http://cssdesk.com/UezT7

Note that my changes are:

```
.home_icon {padding-top: 10px; height:20px;}
.home_icon:before {top:0px;}
```

This works because you have one line of text and you know what size you want the container to be.  It's not a general solution to aligning text vertically, but it works in your specific case.

**Edit:** @marlenunez's answer is better than mine, I would go his route.